# Html send email w/ option to be sent by gmail, outlook.com, etc

Tags: email

I am using a HTML 5 email form. Instead of using 'mailto', I would like the user to have the option of using outlook.com, hotmail, yahoo, gmail, etc. instead of opening their mail client (unless they choose to. My email address should be automatically filled in the To: field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
 
The program-client that the user will use when clicking in a `mailto` link is based on the **preferred settings of the user's browser or  using extensions**(again the user is responsible for that).

[Here](http://lifehacker.com/5883372/set-gmail-as-your-browsers-default-email-client-with-a-simple-hack)'s an example for using gmail when clicking a mailto form, I repeat this is set by the user